# Vielbein in spherical coordinates

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, reference-frames, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames

Typically, one defines a vielbein $e_\mu^a$ that translates between curved indices $\mu$ and local Lorentz indices $a$, in the sense that
$$g_{\mu\nu}=\eta_{ab}e_\mu^a e_\nu^b,$$
where $\eta$ is the Minkowski metric. Usually, one takes the Minowski metric to be
$$\eta=\text{diag}(-1,+1,...,+1),$$
but, in principle, it should also be allowed to take $\eta$ to be the Minkowski metric in spherical coordinates
$$\eta=\text{diag}(-1,+1,r^2,r^2\sin^2\theta,...).$$
Then, for Minkowski space,
$$ds^2=-dt^2+dr^2+r^2(d\theta^2+r^2\sin^2\theta d\phi^2+...),$$
we should have that the vielbein (as a matrix) is
$$e=\text{diag}(1,1,...,1).$$
This then seems to imply that the spin connection is zero, which seems fishy since the Christoffel symbols do not vanish in spherical coordinates. So, my question is: is the spin connection zero in these coordinates, or is there a flaw in my logic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vielbeins are a way to write coordinates of the tangent bundle in a way that does not depend on the coordinates on the underlying manifold.  In the cases typically viewed in GR this involves restricting to *orthonormal frames* for the tangent bundle coordinates.  This is why the equation
$$
g_{\mu\nu}=\eta_{ab}e_\mu^a e_\nu^b,
$$
is relating the coordinate metric, $g_{\mu\nu}$, to the flat space metric $\eta_{ab}$, but in general the metric on the RHS could be of a more general form.

In order to obtain the correct answer for the case you are examining you should not have the spherical coordinate, flat space, metric $\eta_s$ on both sides of this equation.  Rather $\eta_s$ should be on the LHS while the flat coordinate $\eta$ should be on the RHS.  This would ultimately result in the vielbeins being directly related to the Jacobian of the transformation used to obtain spherical coordinates.